# How to retrieve whole document in mongodb distinct query rather than only the key?

Tags: mongodb, distinct, morphia

Mongodb distinct command returns the list of distinct keys in a given document.

Is there any way to retrieve the whole document rather than only keys using mongodb java driver or morphia?

In the documentation it says:

> When possible, the distinct command will use an index to find the documents in the query as well as to return the data.

How does this work, when I try using java driver it always returns the list of keys to my queries. And it doesn't take limit and order queries into consideration. Is it possible to give a order by and limit queries into distinct query?

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: This can be easily done with map-reduce

Comment: This can be better done with the aggregation framework using $group

Comment: I implemented a map-reduce function for solving my problem. Just a note: Writing a map-reduce function in java is quite a pain =)